# CSS: Place Div after the end of paragraph, on the same line

Tags: css

i have paragraphs with text and a div what say something like "more" like this:

```
<div>
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametm.
    </p>
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.
    </p>

    <div class="extra">more</div>
</div>
```

I need to place the extra div right behind the end of the last word in the paragraph, on the same line.

like this: this is the end of p - more

It seems to be easy to do this with a p:after selector but i cant use this because i need to work with the "extra" div in jquery.

And I need to have the paragraph using display or display-inline.

Do somebody has a tip?
thanks alot!

edit: I need to have the extra-div next to - not wrapped in - the p
thats is the problem

and i tried to use span and inside-block but without any luck

Comment: Have you tried using ``span`` instead of a ``div``?

Comment: i cant wrap the extra-div in the paragraph

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametm.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod. 
<span class="extra">more</span>   
        </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks but i cant wrap the extra-div in the paragraph.

Comment: @buckdanny : `div` is a `block-level element` while `span` is an `inline element`. So `div` forces the element to start on a new line and also  takes up the full width available. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `display: inline-block` on the div?

That lets the element have width, height (and other box properties like padding), but behave like a character in a paragraph when it comes to positioning.

Oh also, you probably have to place the div within the last paragraph since otherwise, the paragraph will push it down - the paragraph has its own box in the page.

Answer (score 0):

i cant wrap the span inside the p because the p is coming from a wordpress loop.
at the end i used jquery to append the span at the end of the last p.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.extra_available  p:last-of-type').append(' <span class="extra"> extra </span>');  
});
```

thanks alot!